# XCUITest and UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, xcuitest

How do you access a UIActivityViewController (share / actions sheet) in XCUITest? According to the Accessibility Inspector, t is comprised of several UICollectionViews, which makes it hard to disambiguate the sheet itself.

Querying for `XCUIApplication().sheets.count` returns `0` when the sheet is presented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out, when using the view debugger, the sheet is accessible via a somewhat hidden accessibilityIdentifier of `ActivityListView` (as of Xcode 9.2). It can be accessed with:

```
XCUIApplication().otherElements["ActivityListView"]
```

Note that the "Cancel" button is added to the window separately, so it not a child of the activity controller and must be accessed with

```
XCUIApplication().buttons["Cancel"]
```

Comment: Has this changed for iOS 13? This doesn't work when running my test on iOS 13 simulators anymore.

Comment: @andromedainiative this still works on iOS 15.0. You can check the identifier by typing 'po app' in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on xcode 12.2 with iOS 14.2:

`XCUIApplication().otherElements.element(boundBy: 1).buttons.element(boundBy: <insert button index here>).tap()`

Possible button index numbers:

- 0: Cancel
- 1: Copy
- 2: Markup
- 3: Print
- 4: Save to files

Comment: This approach I get the following error:
`Failed to synthesize event: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button, error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 3118, elementOrHash.elementID: 4354340448.106. (Underlying Error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 3118, elementOrHash.elementID: 4354340448.106) `